# Override Background property of UserControl

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls, blend

I have a `UserControl` `RoundButton.xaml` :

```
<UserControl x:Class="app.controls.RoundButton"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d">
    <Grid>
        <Border x:Name="_Border" Background="Cyan" CornerRadius="2" >
            <Border.Effect>
                <DropShadowEffect x:Name="_Shadow" BlurRadius="0" ShadowDepth="1" Direction="270" Color="White"/>
            </Border.Effect>
           <Button x:Name="_Button" Content="RoundButton" Background="{x:Null}" BorderThickness="0" Padding="10,0,10,0"/>
        </Border>     
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

`RoundButton.xaml.cs` :

```
namespace app.controls
{
    public partial class RoundButton : UserControl
    {
        public RoundButton() { InitializeComponent(); }

        [EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Always), Browsable(true), DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Visible)]
        public new Brush Background
        {
            get { return _Border.Background; }
            set { _Border.Background = value; }
        }
    }
}
```

And I want to be able to change the `Background` property in Blend.

When I define the `Background` property as new, changing it in Blend does not affect my button.
When I define it as override i get the error : `Error   1   'app.controls.RoundButton.Background.get': cannot override inherited member 'System.Windows.Controls.Control.Background.get' because it is not marked virtual, abstract, or override`

What is the best way to override `UserControl` properties in order to be able to modify them in Blend ?

**EDIT:**
A workaround that I found is to rename all `RoundButton` properties and block the `UserControl` properties form being displayed in Blend :

```
public new Brush _Background
{
    get { return _Border.Background; }
    set { _Border.Background = value; }
}
[Browsable(false)]
public new Brush Background { get; set; }
```

Comment: Does Blend support custom dependency properties (it must)? Then don't make `new Background`, but make a simple `SomeBackground` property.

Comment: Yes, if I rename the property it works fine in Blend, I just want to reuse the property Background in order to avoid the confusion

Comment: You are mixing up two different things: normal properties (as you are trying to work with `UserControl.Background`) and *dependency* property (what `UserControl.Background` is). Won't work. You can't expose some property of `_border` to be visible without making it dependency property of your user control and you surely should override default `UserControl.Background` like this (there is **still** [`Control.Background`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.control.background.aspx) dependency property).

Comment: I think I don't understand how this properties are working. For example if I rename the `Background` to `_Background` I can see it in Bend, modify it and the Button will change color. I tried adding a `DepaendencyProperty public static readonly DependencyProperty BackgroundProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Background", typeof(Brush), typeof(RoundButton));` but it's not linked to _Border, so changing it in Blend has no effect on the button. Can you, please, point me to an similar example ?

Comment: You can try to [override](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5653472/1997232) existing dependency property and set [own event handler](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8830205/1997232).