# Wpf how to automatically closed previous popup when start new popup

Tags: c#, wpf, popup

I have a window that contains `popup`.when the operation was performed, this popup called.now i want to for example when user continuous `insert` data and show popup , previous called popup closed.because collisions occur.
my code is :

```
public partial class AvinPopup : Window
{
    static AvinPopup _popup;
    static int timePopup = 0;
    static string textPopUp = "";

    private AvinPopup()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    private static void StartCloseTimer()
    {
        DispatcherTimer timer = new DispatcherTimer();
        timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds((double)timePopup);
        timer.Tick += TimerTick;
        timer.Start();
    }

    private static void TimerTick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DispatcherTimer timer = (DispatcherTimer)sender;
        timer.Stop();
        timer.Tick -= TimerTick;
        _popup.Close();
        _popup.popup.IsOpen = false;

    }
    public static void Show(string _textPopup, int _timePopup = 3)
    {
        timePopup = _timePopup;
        textPopUp = _textPopup;

        Thread newWindowThread = new Thread(ThreadStartPopup);
        newWindowThread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
        newWindowThread.IsBackground = true;
        newWindowThread.Start();
    }

    private static void ThreadStartPopup()
    {

        _popup = new AvinPopup();
        _popup.popup.VerticalOffset = System.Windows.SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenHeight - 200;
        _popup.popup.HorizontalOffset = 100; /*System.Windows.SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenWidth +100;*/
        _popup.txtPopup.Text = textPopUp;
        _popup.Show();
        StartCloseTimer();
        System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Run();
    }
```

Comment: Here is your answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8828240/listen-to-dependencyproperty-changed-event-and-get-the-old-value

Comment: Why don't you check in your Show method or ThreadStartPopup method whether a popup is already open or not...?

Comment: @elgonzo how to check it?

Answer (score 0):

```
private static readonly ManualResetEventSlim _Blocker = new ManualResetEventSlim(false);

private static void ThreadStartPopup()
{
    _Blocker.Reset();
    System.Windows.Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal, new Action(() =>
    {
        if (_popup != null && _popup.IsOpen)
            _popup.IsOpen = false;

         _Blocker.Set();
    }));

    _Blocker.Wait();
    _popup = new AvinPopup();
    _popup.popup.VerticalOffset = System.Windows.SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenHeight - 200;
    _popup.popup.HorizontalOffset = 100; /*System.Windows.SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenWidth +100;*/
    _popup.txtPopup.Text = textPopUp;
    _popup.Show();
    StartCloseTimer();
    System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Run();
}
```

Comment: I get error : The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it.

Comment: Ok I have edited my example. Now the new `Thread` is activating a `ManualResetEventSlim` Blocker. Then call a `Dispatcher Operation` and after it has finished, the new `Thread` is continuing.

Comment: Again get this error.Error is from this code : `if (_popup != null && _popup.popup.IsOpen)` and `_popup.popup.IsOpen` is null. Description error : **StackTrace " at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.VerifyAccess()  at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherObject.VerifyAccess()  at System.Windows.DependencyObject.GetValue(DependencyProperty dp)  at System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.Popup.get_IsOpen()  at <>x.<>m0(<>c <>4__this)string**