# WPF: Drawing parts of a custom control in OnApplyTemplate: how to update?

Tags: c#, wpf, viewmodel

I can successfully draw part of a custom control in the control's `OnApplyTemplate` method, however, this method is called only once and does not appear to be called when I called `ApplyTemplate` when the control's `Num` property changes.

Here is the custom control's code:

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace Cc1
{
    public class CirclesControl : Control
    {
        static CirclesControl()
        {
            DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(CirclesControl), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(CirclesControl)));
        }

        public int Num
        {
            get { return (int)GetValue(NumProperty); }
            set { SetValue(NumProperty, value); }
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty NumProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("Num", typeof(int), typeof(CirclesControl), new PropertyMetadata(2, new PropertyChangedCallback(OnNumChanged)));

        private static void OnNumChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (d is CirclesControl control)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"Num changed - value is now {control.Num}");
                control.ApplyTemplate();
            }
        }

        public override void OnApplyTemplate()
        {
            base.OnApplyTemplate();
            var canvasPart = Template.FindName("Part_Canvas", this);
            if (canvasPart is Canvas canvas)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < Num; i++)
                {
                    var circle = new Ellipse
                    {
                        Height = 50,
                        Width = 50,
                        Fill = Brushes.Red,
                        Stroke = Brushes.Green
                    };
                    canvas.Children.Add(circle);
                    Canvas.SetLeft(circle, i * 55);
                    Canvas.SetTop(circle, 50);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I know that `OnNumChanged` is called because `System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine` writes a message to the output window. `OnNumChanged` also calls `ApplyTemplate` but this does not cause `OnApplyTemplate` to be called.

Here is the main window's xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="Cc1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Cc1"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="1024">
<Window.DataContext>
    <local:ViewModel/>
</Window.DataContext>
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding NumberOfCircles}" FontSize="36"/>
        <local:CirclesControl Num="{Binding NumberOfCircles}"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

The `generic.xaml` for the control:

```
<ResourceDictionary
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Cc1">


    <Style TargetType="{x:Type local:CirclesControl}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:CirclesControl}">
                    <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                            BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                            BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
                        <Canvas x:Name="Part_Canvas"/>
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

And the viewmodel:

```
using System;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Threading;

namespace Cc1
{
    public class ViewModel : DependencyObject
    {
        public ViewModel()
        {
            var timer = new DispatcherTimer
            {
                Interval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(500)
            };
            timer.Tick += (s, e) =>
            {
                NumberOfCircles++;
                if (NumberOfCircles == 10)
                {
                    NumberOfCircles = 2;
                }
            };
            timer.Start();
        }
        public int NumberOfCircles
        {
            get { return (int)GetValue(NumberOfCirclesProperty); }
            set { SetValue(NumberOfCirclesProperty, value); }
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty NumberOfCirclesProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("NumberOfCircles", typeof(int), typeof(ViewModel), new PropertyMetadata(4));
    }
}
```

The number of circles (in the view model) changes all the time (this is what the dispatcher timer does). The `TextBlock` on the main windows accurately reflects the number of circles however the `CirclesControl` custom control on the main window does not update.

Grateful for any hints as to what is missing.

Comment: You can move that part into a method, add `canvas.Children.Clear()` in beginning and call it from [propdp changed event](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8830205/1997232)... but you know how flexible WPF is? What if somewhere you want to use this control with rectangles instead of ellipses or change their color/size? Moving that hard-coded part into xaml and using bindings/data templates/triggers might be a better idea in a long go.

Comment: @sinatr, thanks. Creating a method which adds circles to the canvas solves the problem. I wouldn't mind knowing why `OnApplyTemplate` isn't called when I call `ApplyTemplate` though.

On your second point, moving the code into XAML is not an option - the example I gave is not a real-world example, but just a small project I created to illustrate the problem. The real-world code is a much more complex control which cannot be drawn using XAML.

Comment: *"why OnApplyTemplate isn't called when I call ApplyTemplate"* - the assumption what calling `XXX` will call `OnXXX` is wrong. `XXX` will do something and sometimes (if conditions are appropriate, certain event should be rised, etc.) call `virtual OnXXX`. Keyword - *sometimes* (you can see [source](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/src/Framework/System/Windows/FrameworkElement.cs,351)).